# How can I open external websites in Excel 2011 for Mac? 

Tags: excel, vba, macos

In Excel 2010 it's really easy for me to make a macro that opens a website, selects data from the website, and pastes it into a workbook.

I've searched everywhere to figure out how I can do it on my Mac running Excel 2011, but I'm guessing that since they are just [reintroducing VBA into the Mac version of Office](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/apple/vba-to-make-its-triumphant-return-to-excel-2011-for-mac/7755) that it may not have the capabilities (yet).

Can you help me figure out how to do this if it is possible?